# Is it true that the empty set is contained in every Cartesian Product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true to say that $\forall A,B$ (set)
$\emptyset \subseteq A\times B $

Or: The empty set is contained in every Cartesian Product? (As it is contained in every set).

Comment: The product is still a set, so this is true.

Comment: Are you able to find an element of the empty set which is not an element of the product?

Comment: @Sigur: Why didn't you post your comment as an formal answer. I think, if you did, then the OP would remind something important from logic. +1 for you.

Comment: you asked "contained" in the title but symbolically wrote "is a subset f" in your question body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the product of two sets is a set then the answer is yes.

Now it depends on how you were taught:

- It could be that you were taught naively, and then you were just given the axiom that the product of two sets is a set. Maybe it wasn't even called an axiom, just a definition which said that $A\times B$ is a set.
- It could be that you were taught axiomatically and were given the axiom of pairing, i.e. for every two elements $x,y$ there is an ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ and then you construct $A\times B$ using the replacement axiom, $A\times B=\{\langle a,b\rangle\mid a\in A\land b\in B\}$.
- It could be that you were taught that $\langle a,b\rangle=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ (or some other encoding of ordered pairs via sets), and then using subset axiom (or replacement, again) you can deduce that $A\times B\subseteq\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A\cup B))$ (in the case given here, but you may have $\mathcal P(A\cup\mathcal P(B))$ instead if you encode ordered pairs differently).

In all these cases the Cartesian product of two sets is a set, and therefore $\varnothing$ is a subset of this product. Why is this point so important? Because we define $\subseteq$ as a relation between *sets*, and then we can extend it to larger collections by one trick or another.

Of course you can ask yourself generally whether or not the definition of $\subseteq$ holds, i.e. every element of the empty set is an element of $A\times B$. Of course this holds vacuously, there is no counterexample.  But then there is a delicate issue about how to apply the definition of $\subseteq$ to non-sets. But once you know that $A\times B$ is a collection of objects from your universe it should suffice to conclude that $\varnothing\subseteq A\times B$ is a legitimate and meaningful sentence.

Answer (score 2):

For every set $S$ one has $\emptyset\subseteq S$.

Given sets $A$ and $B$, let $S=A\times B$.

$S$ is a set, so ...

Comment: And why might $S$ be a set?

Comment: @peoplepower, just make use of the **Axiom of pairing** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing

Comment: @Sigur and, of course, the axiom of power set as well as the axiom of replacement.

Answer (score 1):

*[Following the suggestion from @Babak Sorouh]*

Are you able to find an element of the empty set which is not an element of the product?

This is the reason!

Comment: In fact, $p\to q$ is always a true statement when $p$ is always a wrong term.

Comment: Are you able to find an element of the empty set which *is* an element of the product?

Comment: @alancalvitti, your statement does not solve the problem since even if I'd be able to find one element it would not be sufficient to obtain the inclusion.

Comment: Not meant to solve the original problem, just a comment on constructive versus nonconstructive math.

Comment: @alancalvitti, since you just copied the phrase I thought that you were correcting.